# How to access an external application using vba which responds only to mouse clicks

Tags: vba, excel, mouse

I am trying to automate a task at work using vba where i load certain files to an application and generate a zip file. But this application doesn't respond to keyboard commands while loading a file. I'll have to double click the mouse next to the file name and select the file. Any idea how i can automate this using vba? I am not a great coder, so any kind of help would be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance [As shown in this picture, the select option appears only when i click the mouse in the specific tab, and I'll have to click again to select the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvbNy.png)

Comment: I think you'll need to go down the API route, do you know if there is a reference for you for this app?  Check the references see if there is anything that may help.

Comment: HI Nathan_Sav , I did check for the reference and didn't find any, as this application is provided by the clients and there is nothing much i can do to this application apart from accessing it as provided

Comment: Google using Windows API, it will give some demo's that show you the output to Excel, then you can look for the window you'll need and experiment with that.  Number 5 in this should be a start http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-plus-of-my-favorite-windows-api-functions-to-use-in-office-applications/

Comment: and this one will help, http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=52